# wordpress nav loaded into select if more than 6 items

Tags: jquery, wordpress, select, nav

Im looking to create a responsive wordpress nav which a user can add say 15 menu items and after 6 items the remaining 9 would appear in a select field on the nav. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hello Justin and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).